# Change child element state when hovering on parent using CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, icons

I want to activate hover state of icon that is defined from 3rd party and imported into project.

I would like to get CSS only solution and overwriting existing rules would be pointless as every icon has different change / property which would require a lot of retyping.

HTML

```
<a class="activate-hover-state-on-both" href="#">
  <icon class="profile"></icon> Profile
</a>
```

CSS

```
.activate-hover-state-on-both:hover > icon {
 // ACTIVATE HOVER STATE AS STYLES ARE INHERITED FROM 3rd PARTY AND NOT OVERWRITE BEHAVIOUR
}
```

If there is no option using pure CSS what are my options using VanillaJS ?

Comment: you should add icon instead of class name profile

Comment: "overwriting existing rules would be pointless as every icon has different change / property which would require a lot of retyping." -- What do you mean?